# I created a Linked server to SQL Azure but cannot see tables in the Management Studio view?

Tags: sql-server

I ran all the following:

On the remote master database:

```
CREATE LOGIN user1
    WITH PASSWORD = 'Password22++' 
GO
```

On the remote authentication database:

```
CREATE USER user1
    FOR LOGIN user1
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = authentication
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'db_owner', N'user1'
GO
```

On the local database:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver
       @server = N'AZ3',
       @srvproduct=N'Any',
       @provider=N'MSDASQL',
       @datasrc=N'AZ3'
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
       @rmtsrvname=N'AZ3',
       @useself=N'False',
       @locallogin=NULL,
       @rmtuser=N'user1',
       @rmtpassword='Password22++'
GO
```

I see the linked server has been created but when I look at it and try to see the following message:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo) The OLE DB Provier
>   "MSDASQL" for linked server "AZ3" reported an error.
>
> Authentication failed.

Are there some more roles I should grant?

Also if I just want to do a select on a table such as the 'ABC' table in the database `authentication` on the remote then how should I code that SQL ?

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([AZ3],'SELECT * FROM dbo.AspNetRoles')
```

But this also gives me an error:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "AZ3" returned message "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
>       OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "AZ3" returned message "[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetRoles'.".
>       Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>       Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "AZ3".

Comment: Did you follow this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/08/linked-servers-to-sql-azure.aspx ?